# Events in Managed C++: Problem with Events, WindowEvents

Tags: managed-c++

Working on a VisStudio 2008 addin, using managed C++ (C++/CLR in the New Project wizard).

In the OnConnection() function, I want to add a handler to the WindowEvents collection.

When I do this:
    // Hook up events
    EnvDTE::Events ^ events = _applicationObject->Events;
    EnvDTE::WindowEvents ^winEvents = events->WindowEvents();

I get an error message:
 error C2660: 'EnvDTE::Events::WindowEvents::get' : function does not take 0 arguments

In the Object Browser I find this:
public EnvDTE.WindowEvents WindowEvents(EnvDTE.Window WindowFilter = null) { get; }

Thanks for any hints about what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: If I change the call to something like
winEvents = events->WindowEvents(0);
I still get the "does not take 0 arguments" error.
Arggh.
EnvDTE::FindEvents ^fe = events->FindEvents;
works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
EnvDTE::Events ^ events = _applicationObject->Events;
_winEvents = events->WindowEvents[nullptr];
```

Note the square brackets...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
EnvDTE::WindowEvents ^winEvents = events->WindowEvents;
```

without the ().  WindowEvents is a property not a method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the compiler seems to not care... Same result: "'get' does not take 0 arguments".